# Pass an array of enums in C#

Tags: c#, authorize-attribute

I need to allow multiple roles to have access to a method, in a controller in C# Web api.

I have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` which takes an enum of role type, how can I make it so it accepts multiple enums ie. a variable length array of enums.

This is the code I have written for the `Attribute`:

```
private readonly RoleEnum roleInApplication;

public ScopeAuthorizeAttribute(RoleEnum roleInApplication)
{
    this.roleInApplication = roleInApplication;
}

public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    .......
    var relatedPermisssionRole = (db call to get the rolename..etc)
    RoleEnum role;
    if (Enum.TryParse(relatedPermisssionRole, out role) && role == roleInApplication)
    {
            // Succeed if the scope array contains the required scope
            return;
     }
  }

    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
}
```

And in the controller, I use it like this:

```
[ScopeAuthorize(RoleEnum.ADMIN)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(MyModel model)
```

How do I allow multiple roles? eg.

```
[ScopeAuthorize(RoleEnum.ADMIN, RoleEnum.USER)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(MyModel model)
```

Comment: I think you need [`[Flags]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Are you aware of flag enums?  This allows you to distinctly combine multiple enums into a single enum using a bitwise or.

Comment: @Sweeper Worth noting that the flags attribute does *almost nothing* to functionality other than change the output of `ToString`. (oh and `Enum.IsDefined` and `Enum.Parse`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) as in `public ScopeAuthorizeAttribute(params RoleEnum[] roleInApplication)` but in reality you are trying to solve the issue in the wrong way, consider using [`Flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8) instead:

```
[FlagsAttribute] 
enum Role
{
  None = 0,
  Admin = 1,
  User = 2,
  SomeOtherRole = 4
}
```

Then you can pass your roles as one parameter using bitwise OR:

```
[ScopeAuthorize(Role.Admin | Role.User)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(MyModel model)
```

But don't just copy my code snippet, it is definitely worth having a good read of the documentation for [`Flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8)  esp. [`Guidelines for FlagsAttribute and Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8#guidelines-for-flagsattribute-and-enum) to ensure you use this pattern correctly. There are a few caveats you must be aware of, which are not immediately obvious. It will be a 5 minutes well spent.

Also, I suggest you refrain from suffixing your enum with the word `Enum` and using UPPERCASE for your enum names.

Comment: Accepted @Leonardo's solution,works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: If you suggest using the `Flags` attribute, then you should probably also explain that it does almost nothing by itself and you need to explicitly set the enum values to powers of two.

Answer (score 3):

You can create constructor param. I'm updating the code as below.

```
private readonly List<RoleEnum> roleInApplications;

public ScopeAuthorizeAttribute(params RoleEnum[] roleInApplications)
{
    this.roleInApplications = roleInApplications.toList();
}
```